# Looping thru facebook API array

Tags: php, facebook

I have successfully gotten the info that I need from the facebook API. I wanted to get my favorite athletes and my favorite sports teams. My favorite sports teams are stored in a php array by default. It looks like this:

```
[favorite_teams] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39523792780
                    [name] => New York Yankees
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 286845273454
                    [name] => New York Giants
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8725012666
                    [name] => Boston Celtics
                )

        )
```

But, when I try to loop through and display all of them, it doesn't quite work. Here is the code for looping through that I have attempted to do.

```
    $numba = count($user_profile['favorite_teams']);

    for($i = 0;$i < $numba;++$i)
    {
         echo $user_profile['favorite_teams']['$i']['name'];
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the error or the warning that you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. It's just not display what it's supposed to.

Comment: You should be using foreach. Its much more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:-

```
$numba = count($user_profile['favorite_teams']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numba; $i++)
{
    echo $user_profile['favorite_teams'][$i]['name'];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Neal - I suppose that the string "`'$i'`" in the "`echo`" statement for the array index is going wrong which has been posted by the OP. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit different. It should be $i instead of '$i'. The quotes were unnecessary. And  mixed up ++$i with $i++. Thanks for the answer. I have a tendency to make careless syntax errors every now and then.

Comment: @Lance - Please check it first, then if you are satisfied, you can mark my answer as the correct one. ;)

Comment: On a side note, do you know much about the facebook API?

Comment: First of all, thanks. No I don't know much on Facebook API, as I'm too much focused on Magento. However, you can always post questions here & there are many SO users who will be able to answer your queries :)